# Message ordinal-number by enqueuing order

Tags: multithreading, message-queue, ibm-mq

My application (.NET-based) gets messages from a queue in a multithreaded fashion and I'm worried about the fact that I may receive messages in an out-of-order manner because one thread can be quicker than the other, for instance, given the following queue state:

***[Message-5 | Message-4 | Message-3 | Message-2 | Message-1]***

In a multithreaded operation, **msg #2** may arrive before **msg #1**, even though **msg #1** was first in the queue, due to many threading issues (thread time slices, thread scheduling etc).

In such a situation, it would be great if a message that is inside the queue have already stamped with an ordinal/sequence number when it was enqueued and even if I get the messages in an out of order fashion, I can still order them at some point within my application using their given ordinal-number attribute.

Any known mechanism to achieve it in a **Websphere MQ** environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

(1) Use Message Grouping in MQ as whitfiea mentioned or

(2) Change you application to be single threaded.

Note: If the sending application does not set the MQMD MsgId field then the queue manager will generate a unique number (based on queue manager name, date & time) and store it in the message's MQMD MsgID field.

Comment: Thank for the answer, what if I'll use the message's `timestamp` attribute, couldn't it be good enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the `MessageSequenceNumber` from the MQMessage if the messages are put to the queue in a message group. The MessageSquenceNumber will either be the order that the messages were put to the queue by default or defined by the application that put the messages to the queue.

See the `MessageSequenceNumber` [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, can you please elaborate little more about this feature?

Comment: The feature would be to big to describe in a SO comment so I recommend reading this: (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026270_.htm) and this: (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023060_.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the originating message has an ordinal then as you receive your data you could:

Use a thread safe dictionary:

```
SortedDictionary<int,Message>
```

Comment: The issue is that I first need a number to be stamped to the message.

Comment: how would know the order?  If the sent data doesn't have anything to identify order then neither would you, if that is the case then you would want the same thread receiving the entire set of messages in order to guarantee the data is contiguous.